# In app purchase content format

Tags: iphone

I want to develop ebook reader application, from which user can buy ebooks available in itunes connect associated with this application.

My Question is: when user pays for ebook, that ebook will be accessible by this application only,

Or it will get download to iphone itself? and will this ebook be consider as single iphone application ?

Thanks,

Jayesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: yes in-app purchase programming guide explains all stuff related to content that can be bought from iTunes connect, but i want to buy purchase other application from my application in iphone. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Nope, can't be done. You can send the user to an app's page in the App Store, from which they can buy that app as usual, but you definitely can't install other apps from your own.

Comment: ok Noah, Yes all i can do is redirect user to App Store link, but no way, user can buy application from application. Thanks Noah for reply. it helps